# Saving sensitive info to a file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have aws_acm_certificate terraform resource:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "certificate1" {
  domain_name               = "*.bla.bla.com"
  certificate_authority_arn = aws_acmpca_certificate_authority.subordinate.arn
}
```

and I need to save the private_key of this certificate to a file (in order to subsequently zip it and save to s3). When I try to do this

```
resource "local_sensitive_file" "private_key_file" {
  content  = "${aws_acm_certificate.certificate1.private_key}"
  filename = "${path.module}/files/certs/privateKey.pem"

  depends_on = [
      aws_acm_certificate.certificate1
  ]
}
```

I get an error in "terraform plan":

```
Error: Invalid combination of arguments
│
│   with local_sensitive_file.private_key_file,
│   on acm.tf line 147, in resource "local_sensitive_file" "private_key_file":
│  147: resource "local_sensitive_file" "private_key_file" {
│
│ "content_base64": one of `content,content_base64,source` must be specified
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of arguments
│
│   with local_sensitive_file.private_key_file,
│   on acm.tf line 147, in resource "local_sensitive_file" "private_key_file":
│  147: resource "local_sensitive_file" "private_key_file" {
│
│ "source": one of `content,content_base64,source` must be specified
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of arguments
│
│   with local_sensitive_file.private_key_file,
│   on acm.tf line 148, in resource "local_sensitive_file" "private_key_file":
│  148:   content  = "${aws_acm_certificate.emr_cluster_certificate1.private_key}"
│
│ "content": one of `content,content_base64,source` must be specified
```

I tried to use local_file resource instead, but still got similar error. I also tried to use content_base64 argument instead, but essentially the same error.

Questions:

What am I doing wrong here?
Is it possible to save sensitive info to a file in terraform?

Comment: I think the key might be base64 encoded. Also, you don't need the `content  = "${aws_acm_certificate.certificate1.private_key}"`, you can do `content  = aws_acm_certificate.certificate1.private_key`.

Comment: I tried to use content_base64 instead - the same error. Also removing "" does not help.

Comment: Can you check in terraform console if `aws_acm_certificate` actually outputs the private key file?

Comment: It does not allow to output aws_acm_certificate.certificate1.private_key, the error is "Error: Output refers to sensitive values
│
│   on outputs.tf line 18:
│   18: output "certificate_files" {
│
│ To reduce the risk of accidentally exporting sensitive data that was intended to be only internal, Terraform requires that any root module output containing sensitive data
│ be explicitly marked as sensitive, to confirm your intent.
│
│ If you do intend to export this data, annotate the output value as sensitive by adding the following argument:
│     sensitive = true"

Comment: if I specify sensitive = true in the output variable - it outputs it as "certificate_files = (sensitive value)"

Comment: You can append `-raw` to display the value if using `terraform output` command.

Comment: hm, terraform output returns null for private_key

Comment: So, I don't think that will work. Do you have a private cert authority?

Comment: The `private_key` argument is available only when you are importing an existing certificate. From what I can tell, you are creating a new one based on the Private CA you have created. So you probably have to reconsider how to get the private key.